# Refresh installation form of InstallShield application File

Tags: installshield

I created a setup file using InstallShield application.

Now, in one of the Installation Form, I have a checkbox control. By default it is unchecked. But after performing some operation on that form, I wants to check that checkbox control.

I am able to change its property, but the form is not getting refreshed.

Please Help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation in Windows Installer internal UI.  Either roll an external UI handler ( InstallScript MSI project type for example ) or rethink your UI story to conform to what MSI is capable of doing.

Comment: Thank you for reply.. You are 100% right. In Basic MSI project, we cannot able to refresh the dialog.